# YouTube & Google require separate OAauth2 Authentication for respective APIs

Tags: google-analytics, youtube, oauth-2.0, google-api, youtube-analytics

I have a google account that I use for everything to do with my website: ads, analytics, youtube, etc.

However, since the youtube/google integration (I imagine), When I sign in with my google account and click my profile, this is what I see:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtB1S.png

The top one's name is simply my email address, depicting my main account which I use for analytics, ads and whatnot, the second is my youtube account, and the bottom is an old account I created years ago but never use.

I'm currently using the Google APIs for the backend of my website, specifically Analytics and Youtube Analytics. When I do the oauth2 authorisation process for Analytics, I need to choose the top profile. For youtube however, I need to do another authorisation process and pick the second profile, which is VERY annoying!

It's a mess and I can't find any solutions anywhere. I've tried the gaia_link but it doesn't do what I need.

Comment: I've just worked out how to delete the third profile. Still have a problem in that my youtube and google account are separate and it requires 2 logins regarding oauth2 authorization. I'd like to merge the 2 without losing subscribers!

Comment: When I try to authenticate I always have this choice: http://i.imgur.com/nFuYCef.png , but ideally I'd like it so that it shows only one option which grants an access token to both my site analytics and my youtube analytics